# data.frame in R: one-vs-multiple convert one-vs-one?

Tags: r

original data.frame:

```
UniProt.ID         Drug.IDs
1     P45059          DB00303
2     P19113 DB00114; DB00117
```

I would like change it as follows:

```
UniProt.ID         Drug.IDs
1     P45059          DB00303
2     P19113          DB00114
3     P19113          DB00117
```

do you have a better and efficient way to do it if I have many rows?
Thanks.

Kevin

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your codes to us to check what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split `Drug.IDs` by `;` and `unlist`, then `cbind` the required number of replicates of each `Uniprot.ID` to the unlisted vector:

```
d <- read.csv(text='UniProt.ID,Drug.IDs
P45059,DB00303
P19113,DB00114; DB00117', stringsAsFactors=F)


drugs.split <- strsplit(d$Drug.IDs, '; ')

with(d, cbind(rep(UniProt.ID, sapply(drugs.split, length)), 
              unlist(drugs.split)))


#      [,1]     [,2]     
# [1,] "P45059" "DB00303"
# [2,] "P19113" "DB00114"
# [3,] "P19113" "DB00117"
```

Coerce to `factor` and add `dimnames` as required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fully aware that this may be overkill and there is an easier way.  But this seemed like a question that might be best worked out with a home-made function.  Here's a one that I hope will work on your complete data set.  It works on my end when I add more data than you provided in the post.

The data, naturally coerced to class `factor` by R.

```
UniProt.ID <- c("P45059", "P19113 DB00114;",
                "P57809", "P21548 DB00954;",
                "P48502", "P18456 DB49785;")
Drug.IDs <- c("DB00303", "DB00117", "DB34658")
data2 <- data.frame(UniProt.ID, Drug.IDs)
```

The function.

```
colSplitter <- function(data)
  {
    d <- sapply(data, as.character)
    minChar <- min(sapply(d[,1], nchar))
    new <- sapply(1:nrow(d), function(i){
      if(nchar(d[i, 1]) > minChar){
        newD2 <- gsub(".*\\s|;", "", d[i,1])
        newD1 <- gsub("\\s.*", "", d[i,1])
        rbind(d[i-1, ], c(newD1, d[i, 2]), c(newD1, newD2))
      }
    })
    newDF <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, new))
    return(newDF)
  }
```

The result.

```
> colSplitter(data2)
  UniProt.ID Drug.IDs
1     P45059  DB00303
2     P19113  DB00117
3     P19113  DB00114
4     P57809  DB00303
5     P21548  DB00117
6     P21548  DB00954
7     P48502  DB00303
8     P18456  DB00117
9     P18456  DB49785
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have saved your solution. The data.frame generated by your code is more complex than mine. The code from @jbaums produce the same data.frame with mine.

Comment: No prob.  I had some spare time this afternoon.  Haha.  This function would probably work on other data too.  It's pretty general

Answer (score 0):

How many have the double/triple/quad... ID? You could simply take a subset of the data using grep.

```
ind = grep(' ', data$UniProt.Id)
```

Remove these from the original, create a new data.frame with replicated Uni values and then rbind?

Comment: Yes, have the double/triple/quad...Drug.IDs for each UniProt.ID.